# Waiting for async operations

Tags: c++

I want to implement a mechanism that allows me to block program flow until an async operation has completed. (Mostly to be used in unit tests where there is no message loop.)

The code I have creates a thread and waits for a condition notification inside the thread:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>

struct Blocker {
    Blocker() :
        wait_thread([this]() {
            std::mutex mtx;
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);            
            cond.wait(lck);
        })
    {
    }

    void wait() { wait_thread.join(); }

    void notify() { cond.notify_one(); }

    std::condition_variable cond;    
    std::thread wait_thread;
};

template<typename Callback>
void async_operation(const Callback & cb) { cb(); }

int main() {
    Blocker b;
    async_operation([&](){ b.notify(); });
    b.wait();
}
```

The problem is that it often deadlocks because the call to `notify` occurs before the thread even started. How should I fix this?

Comment: Condition variables are not windows event objects.

Comment: Do you know [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)? I don't know if this helps, but it sounds like it should ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

struct blocker
{
  blocker () : done (false) {}

  void
  notify ()
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock (m);
    done = true;
    c.notify_all (); 
  }

  void
  wait ()
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock (m);
    while (!done)
      c.wait (lock);
  }

  bool done;
  std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable c;
};
```

Comment: Surely this introduces a UB data race on `done`- it's not atomic.

Comment: Surely it's accessed only under lock.

Comment: Aargh, why couldn't I think of that myself..? Anyway, thanks!